# What is the difference between application gateway, api gateway, api management, api apps and app services when it comes to hosting api

Tags: azure-api-management, api-gateway, azure-application-gateway, azure-appservice, azure-api-apps

I want to understand the difference between the following services when it comes to hosting api's on Azure

application gateway,
api gateway,
api management,
api apps,
app services

A simple and understandable example would be helpful as these services can get really confusing.

Answer (score 3):

Azure Application Gateway and Azure API Management are no hosting solutions. They are solution to, simply put, manage traffic. Think about topics like Protection, [load balancing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/guide/technology-choices/load-balancing-overview), SSL termination, Header modification, Routing etc. They could very well be combined. See [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/apis/protect-apis) for some guidance.

Azure Functions and Azure Web Apps are 2 hosting options, the former is a serverless offering that allows pay-per-use and Web Apps require an App Service Plan for which you pay a fixed price based on the provisioned resources.

api apps and api gateway you mention I cannot map to an azure service.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/guide/technology-choices/compute-decision-tree) is a decision tree that can help clearify things regarding hosting options.